# How do I load one bean or another depending on the profile?

Tags: java, spring

I have two beans that implement the same interface. I have annotated one with:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Profile;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
@Profile("production")
public class MailServiceImpl implements MailService {
```

And the other one with:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Profile;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
@Profile("test")
public class SinkMailServiceImpl extends MailServiceImpl {
```

Then added the following configuration:

```
spring.profiles.active=test
```

Which successfully logs this when the application starts:

> The following profiles are active: test

However I am getting this error:

> Description:
>
> Field mailService in fr.project.backend.service.impl.UserServiceImpl
> required a single bean, but 2 were found:
> - mailServiceImpl: defined in URL [jar:file:/app/app.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/fr/project/backend/service/impl/MailServiceImpl.class]
> - sinkMailServiceImpl: defined in URL [jar:file:/app/app.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/fr/project/backend/service/impl/SinkMailServiceImpl.class]
>
> Action:
>
> Consider marking one of the beans as @Primary, updating the consumer
> to accept multiple beans, or using @Qualifier to identify the bean
> that should be consumed

I don't want to mark one as `@Primary` statically, and the `@Qualifier` annotation doesn't seem to fit my needs either. How do I load beans depending on the profile?

Comment: How did you set the configuration? What does it say in the log your active profile is when starting up?

Comment: I have added these details in my question

Comment: Please show your imports also. This should work as you expect. (I will also note that it is unusual for a bean to extend another component-annotated bean.)

Comment: I just tried your sample code and it works without errors

Comment: I have added the imports. In order to have a more usual pattern should I have an abstract class that I use with `@Autowired` and then two extending classes annotated with `@Profile`?

Comment: that's weird, but most probably has to do with the fact that your services extend each other

Comment: I have tested the `production` profile and I'm still getting this error

Comment: its weird cause I just tried your code in a clean spring-boot (2.5.4) project and it works. I guess you have already cleaned/built your project right?

Comment: Yes I'm building it from a fresh Docker image every time. I'm using an older release of Spring boot (1.5.7)

Comment: My code is actually public, it is located here: https://github.com/Guerric-P/weflat/tree/test/backend (on the test branch)

Comment: In your github code you have annotated SinkMailServiceImpl with both `production` and `test` profiles and MailServiceImpl has no `@Profile` at all! And that configuration I suppose can lead to the error you are facing. So maybe your changes that you describe in the question here have not been applied to your compiled code?

Comment: wow @pleft indeed I'm just dumb I forgot to push my code... thank you and sorry for the waste of time

Answer (score 0):

I think you can achieve this using the @ConditionalOnProperty(prefix= "spring.profiles", name = "active", havingValue = "test") annotation on your service classes where the property can be anything you like.